# How to use string variables to create variables list for ddply?

Tags: r, plyr

Using R's builtin ToothGrowth example dataset, this works:

```
ddply(ToothGrowth, .(supp,dose), function(df) mean(df$len))
```

But I would like to have the subsetting factors be variables, something like

```
factor1 = 'supp'
factor2 = 'dose'
ddply(ToothGrowth, .(factor1,factor2), function(df) mean(df$len))
```

That doesn't work. How should this be done?

I thought perhaps something like this:

```
factorCombo = paste('.(',factor1,',',factor2,')', sep='') 
ddply(ToothGrowth, factorCombo, function(df) mean(df$len))
```

But it doesn't work either. I think I am close, but not sure the proper way to do it. I suppose the entire command could be put into a string, followed by an eval() call of the string, but hopefully is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
x <- c("supp", "dose") 
ddply(ToothGrowth, x, function(df) mean(df$len))
```

Comment: thanks!  and to use exactly the format I was asking about, the first line would be:  x <- c(factor1, factor2)

Comment: No problem! ddply is godly, once you get it you can pretty much do anything you want.

Comment: Nice. Can you do the same trick with altering variables? Assume you got `x <- c("supp")` and want the grouped mean of len and V1.

Comment: Yes, you can! Use:`ddply(ToothGrowth,.(supp),colwise(mean))`. also works with custom functions!